# Reading from a file in Java

Tags: java, file, text

I wrote a program that reads from a text file using Java. The file has 1 column with a lot of integer values and each value is being added to an array list. However, when I print the array list, between each number I am getting an empty entry. For example if in text file I have:

```
4 
55
```

I am getting:

```
1 : ÿþ4 (Also I do not know what this weird character is)
2 : 
3 : 555
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("ReadingFile.txt");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        input = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();

        int i=1;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();;
            numbers.add(line);
            System.out.println(i + " : " + line);
            i++;
        }
        input.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to avoid using the arraylist and just do :

```
System.out.println(i + " " + line);
```

however this problem is still there so I am guessing that it is not an ArrayList problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing values in different parts of the code to test the logic?

Comment: Did you generate *ReadingFile.txt* yourself ? If so, how ?

Comment: no I am exporting it from an Excel sheet

Comment: @user90790 could you paste the first few lines of your text file? I tried your code with my own text file and it worked fine.

Comment: 337
274
273
212
153
119
124

Comment: your text file is corrupt. Try your code against a text file that you create, and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I tested it with a new text file generated "by hand" and it worked fine as well. I guess because it is from an excel sheet but it doesn't have any weird characters

Comment: how do you know? Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: My best guess is a character encoding issue.

Comment: No it's not corrupted it's beacuse it contains BOM character. take a look at [Remove Byte Order Mark (BOM) Character](http://techwelkin.com/how-to-remove-byte-order-mark-bom-characters).I think your file is encoded with UTF-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your text file is actually a good text file, it could be a character encoding thing. You need to provide the correct character set to your scanner in its constructor. So change the line:

```
input = new Scanner(file);
```

Into something like:

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
input = new Scanner(file, charset);
```

Ofcourse, you need to figure out which character set your file is actually stored as and use that one. I do UTF-8 here only as an example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is that you're actually reading binary from an excel file, hence the strange characters.  If you want to read an excel file directly, then use a library such as JXL (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) - here's a good tutorial for using that API: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html

Otherwise, you would want to save export your excel file to CSV format and read the file with your code.

Answer (score 0):

weird chars should be writeUTF prefix or BOM. so, depends on how you write the file, reading method can be different.

if you write file with DataOutputStream and call writeUTF, then you should read the file with readUTF

if it is a simple text file that was written by a text program, like notepad++, I suggest call trim() function for every line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is UTF-16. These two characters are the Byte order mark of UTF-16.

You must specify that when constructing your Scanner.

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-16");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `Notepad++` (text editor) download it. Open your generated text file using it.

Do find/Replace and populate the fields and check the settings by looking at the image below. then press `Replace All`. And then save your file. Your text file will be clean.

[image]